# unlinking a Google Account from stackexchange

Tags: support, login

If a user has a Google Account, a different website such as the Washington Post, might offer to "link" the Google Account to the Washington Post account. The Washington Post offers both link and unlink features. Presumably when a Google Account is linked from a Washington Post account the Post does not forget the password even though that password no longer needs to be used. After unlinking the user should then be able to login to the Post by typing the password that was earlier provided to the Post.

Where is the "unlink" feature in stackexchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current

[image: My Logins page in profile settings]

Right now, you're set up to where you can log in using either your email and a password, or by clicking the "Log in with Google" button. If you don't want that last option anymore, hit "remove" next to the Google account listed in your profile settings.